# Retrieving sums from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I try to retrieve sum of values for a specific column from 2 tables

In the first table I retrieve sums twice for 2 different conditions

In the second table I retrieve sums once for given conditions

here is my sql co

```
SELECT tafk.ID
     , tafk.KASA_NAME
     , SUM(tafkh.MIKTAR) ODEYEN
     , SUM(tafkh1.MIKTAR) TAHSIL
     , SUM(tafh.MIKTAR) AS HARCAMA
  FROM tbl_agro_fin_kasa tafk
  LEFT 
  JOIN tbl_agro_fin_kasa_hareket tafkh 
    ON tafkh.ODEYEN = tafk.ID
  LEFT 
  JOIN tbl_agro_fin_kasa_hareket tafkh1    
    ON tafkh1.TAHSIL_EDEN = tafk.ID
  LEFT 
  JOIN tbl_agro_fin_harcamalar tafh 
    ON tafh.KASA_ID = tafk.ID
 GROUP 
    BY tafk.ID
```

I observe that my query doubles or triples some retrieved sum values

How should I change my query to get correct results?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: a one to many relation would double or triple the number when joining so start always by joining and then remove the doubles